# Will Protection from Evil and Good protect vs. Charm Person cast by an undead wizard?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, undead, charmed

I'm running *Curse of Strahd*, and have reworked Strahd as an actual wizard and not just a vampire with convenient wizard-powers. One of the spells he has is [*charm person*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/charm-person).

If my PCs cast [*protection from evil and good*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/protection-from-evil-and-good) on themselves, will this protect against *charm person* as cast by an undead?  The specific wording of PfEaG is

> Until the spell ends, one willing creature you touch is protected against certain types of creatures: aberrations, celestials, elementals, fey, fiends, and **undead**.
>
> The protection grants several benefits. Creatures of those types have disadvantage on attack rolls against the target. **The target also can't be charmed, frightened, or possessed by them.** If the target is already charmed, frightened, or possessed by such a creature, the target has advantage on any new saving throw against the relevant effect.

My thinking is that this is intended to protect against things like innate charm abilities (like a [succubus](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/succubus-incubus)).  However, will it also protect against *charm person* IF the caster of said spell is undead?

Comment: What is the creature type of your reworked Strahd? Is he undead or humanoid?

Comment: Still undead! So, RAW, Charm Person is still coming from an undead source, but I wanted to know if other people might also argue for the RAI that Protection is meant for innate charm abilities and not spells.

Answer (score 10):

Your interpretation is correct.  There is no reason to believe the protection of the spell is limited to innate abilities; if it was, it would say so.  [Spells only do what they say they do.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret)

In order to argue the opposite - that it only grants protection from innate abilities - it would be reasonable to point to some other protection method that only protects against innate abilities, but not cast spells.  I don't think you can find such an example.

Comment: Might also be worth pointing out that [spells only do what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret).

Comment: For what it's worth, there are some protections that stop spells but not innate non-spell abilities that have spell-like effects. For example, Leomund's Tiny Hut stops physical attacks and spells, but a dragon's breath passes right through it. So there is a meaningful distinction between the two. However, as you say, I can't think of any that work the other way around, protecting from innate abilities but not spells.

Comment: If you feel you need a further justification for why a cast spell would be blocked by the Protection, from an in-universe perspective, the Protection spell is basically blocking your mind from being touched by the mind/spirit of an undead creature.  A charm is an influence from one mind to another, and it doesn't matter what mechanic allowed that connection to form; the protection spell is still going to 'sense' that the source is an undead (or elemental, fey, fiend, etc) and block the effect.

Comment: @RyanThompson - Okay, it's been awhile, but what makes you think *tiny hut* won't stop dragon's breath?

Comment: The *tiny hut* spell says that it blocks, creatures, objects, spells, and other magical effects. A dragon's breath is none of those, so it is unaffected by the spell. Jeremy Crawford confirms this here: https://www.sageadvice.eu/2018/01/29/does-the-breath-weapon-go-through-leomunds-tiny-hut/

Comment: Wow, I never knew. Seems harsh that it's wouldn't block acid breath, for instance.